# Compute $\int_0^1\frac{\sin{\pi x}}{1+x} \, dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Compute $$\int_0^1\frac{\sin\pi x}{1+x} \, dx.$$
This integral looks concise but I'm stuck in the first place.

I mistakenly wrote this formula in an exercise and I think this would be interesting if it could be solved in an elementary way, which I don't know how.

Comment: any own thoughts? there will be no result in terms of elementary function. see "cosine/sine -integral"

Comment: @tired Actually, I mistakenly wrote this formula in a exercise and I think this would be interesting if it could be solved in an elementary way, which I don't know how. Thanks for your comment, it's helpful to know that this can't be solved in terms of elementary function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $y=\pi(x+1)$. Then $ \sin{\pi x} = \sin{(y-\pi)} = -\sin{y} $, $dx/(x+1) = dy/y $ and the integral is
$$ -\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \frac{\sin{\pi y}}{y} \, dy = -\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\sin{\pi y}}{y} \, dy + \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin{\pi y}}{y} \, dy = \operatorname{Si}(\pi) - \operatorname{Si}(2\pi) $$

Comment: @chappeers ... All to easy  ... +1

Answer (score 2):

by using the Taylor series 
$$\frac{\sin \pi x}{1+x}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^n\frac{(\pi)^{(2n-1)}}{(2n-1)!}(x+1)^{2n-2}$$